# How to use a global boolean variable to make a button toggle 2 images

Tags: javascript

```
function yourFunction() {
   let displayImage = document.getElementById('imahe')
   if(displayImage.src.match('images/cabato.jpg')){
    displayImage.src = 'images/nin.jpg'
   }
   else {
    displayImage.src = 'images/cabato.jpg'
   }
    }
```

Im using simple if/else, need to know how to still make this work by using global boolean variable

Comment: Why do you need a variable in the first place. What exactly is your goal? Why are you adding a restriction of having to use a global Boolean to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in making that change?  What change have you attempted and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: For testing purposes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I post you a code snippet easy to understand and to modify less.

```
let isImageDisplayed = true;
function yourFunction() {
   let displayImage = document.getElementById('imahe')
   if (isImageDisplayed) {
      displayImage.src = 'images/nin.jpg'
   } else {
      displayImage.src = 'images/cabato.jpg'
   }
   isImageDisplayed = !isImageDisplayed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a variable at all. You can use a simple [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) to solve this for a toggle operation.

```js
const imgEl = document.querySelector("img");

// Set up a click event handler
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // A simple ternary operator that checks the current image
  // source and sets it according takes care of this.
  imgEl.src = imgEl.src.includes("happy-smiley-emoticon-face-vector.jpg") ? "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/smile-icon-vector-face-emoticon-260nw-1721368459.jpg"  : "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/008/734/498/small/happy-smiley-emoticon-face-vector.jpg"
});
```

```css
img { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
<img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/008/734/498/small/happy-smiley-emoticon-face-vector.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is state variable `flag` and toggle on button click and re-render image.

```js
let flag = true;
const url1 = "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/leaf-blue.png"
const url2 = "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/leaf-green.png"

function renderImage() {
  const img = document.querySelector("#pic");
  img.src = flag ? url1 : url2;
}

document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", function () {
  flag = !flag;
  renderImage()
});
```

```html
<img id="pic" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/leaf-blue.png">

<button id="toggle"> toggle </button>
```